# Where can I find the S3 image fetch limit settings?

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-s3

Any idea where can I remove the image fetch limit? Because I have images in a Magento site that is hosted in Amazon S3. If I change the image url to S3, it fetches the images including all the thumbnails, but eventually, blocks the thumbnails, and only fetches the main image.

But if I host the image in my other server (Not Amazon S3), it doesn't have any limit. It will fetch all the images again and again, regardless of how many times I refresh it.

Here are examples:

```
www.shoptv.com.ph/active-posture.html - Image hosted in S3
dev.shoptv.com.ph/active-posture.html - Image hosted in Dreamhost
```

As you can see, the thumbnails are all present in DH, but in S3, it doesn't show up. But if you use the direct permalink of the images, it actually shows. For example:

```
Amazon S3:
http://s3.shoptv.com.ph/images/601938/601938-1.jpg
http://s3.shoptv.com.ph/images/601938/601938-2.jpg
http://s3.shoptv.com.ph/images/601938/601938-3.jpg
http://s3.shoptv.com.ph/images/601938/601938-4.jpg

Dreamhost:
http://dostscholars.org/images/601938/601938-1.jpg
http://dostscholars.org/images/601938/601938-2.jpg
http://dostscholars.org/images/601938/601938-3.jpg
http://dostscholars.org/images/601938/601938-4.jpg
```

All the images are present. But if you host it in S3, and include it in your media.phtml in Magento, it just won't show.

I suspect that it has something to do with my Amazon S3 settings, maybe a limit somewhere in the S3 dashboard that I can't find.

Answer (score 3):

There is no image limit in Amazon S3.

Your problem is caused by the fact that the `www.shoptv.com.ph/active-posture.html` page is missing this HTML code (which I got from `dev.shoptv.com.ph/active-posture.html`):

```
<div class="more-views">
<h2>More Views</h2>
<ul class="product-image-thumbs">
```

It isn't displaying the images because there is no HTML telling the web browser to display the images!

Comment: Yep, it doesn't generate the HTML code when it cannot fetch the next images, that's why you cannot see it. T___T

Comment: But when I change the URL from amazon to another host, then it generates the HTML to fetch the images.

Comment: Then you should figure out why it can't fetch the images! Try to obtain an error message from the system that generates the HTML.

Comment: I think I found out, something to do with Cloudflare + my Cname. When I use the direct amazon s3 URL, it fetches images :D

s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com.

But when I use a CNAME, it doesn't. So I'll just stick with the direct url. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: If you are using a `CNAME`, then the bucket name must match the domain name (eg bucket.example.com).

Comment: Yep, it's matching, but it only fetches the first image if I use the CNAME. Thanks. Will just use the direct URL for now until I figure out what's the cause. :D